# Cannot connect to postgresql remotely

Tags: postgresql

I cannot connect to my postgresql instance remotely on port 5432.  Connection times out.  I cannot connect remotely using psql, pgAdmin or telnet.  I feel like I have everything configured correctly.  Postgresql has been restarted several times with these settings.  Remote connection works fine.

What could I be missing?

netstat:
[image]
[image]

postgressql.conf
[image]

pg_hba.conf:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try referring this link for help
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/02/enable-remote-postgresql-connection/?utm_source=tuicool

in short you have to the following steps
1. Add the following line to the pg_hba.conf server. This will allow connection from “192.168.xxx.xx” ip-address (This is the client ip)

```
  # vi  /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
  host    all         all         192.168.xxx.xx/xx    trust
```

2. Change the Listen Address in postgresql.conf

   # grep listen /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
        listen_addresses = '*'
3. Test the Remote Connection

Comment: I followed these instructions with the exception of specifying the client IP address since it is a laptop and the exact IP will change.   Instead I used 0.0.0.0  to specify any IP.  And I don’t want to use trust because I want to still require a password.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the method `md5` to `trust` and and enter the address as `0.0.0.0/0`.

Open the config file

```
vi  /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

Insert the following line

```
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0    trust
```

Maybe it will work.

Comment: This would accept all connections without password.